# __feature__ in PySide6

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

I'd like to use the *__feature__* module in PySide6 to use *snake_case*. Based on the [blog post by Qt](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-for-python-6-released), I'm supposed to be able to use it like this:

```
from __feature__ import snake_case, true_property

table = QTableWidget()
table.column_count = 2

button = QPushButton("Add")
button.enabled = False

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.add_widget(table)
layout.add_widget(button)
```

However, I can't use *__feature__* since my program doesn't know from which package it came from. I tried doing the code above without the import line, but that still doesn't work. What do I do?

Comment: What does *my program doesn't know from which package it came from* mean?

Comment: Are you using an IDE which is complaining about the import?

Comment: @eyllanesc __feature__ is a module from the Qt library, but I don't know which package it belongs to. I'm assuming I have to type something like

```from PySide6.some package I don't know.__feature__ import snake_case, true_property
```

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes. I'm using Pycharm.

Comment: The rules for using `__feature__` is that you import PySide6 first: `from PySide6.some package ` and then  `from __feature__ import snake_case, true_property`. That is to say, after importing PySide6 it is just available to use `__feature__`. Obviate the warnings of your IDE